# Separate Pages for Questions & Solutions

Tags: random-numbers, arithmetic

I am making basic arithmetic worksheets with random numbers.

I want to separate the questions from the answer page. Not sure how to do that.

Ideally, it would look something like this, but with more equations on each page.

**QUESTIONS PAGE**

2+3=__

7=__+4

1+__=9

**ANSWERS PAGE**

2+3=5

7=3+4

1+8=9

My code puts all the questions and answers together, which is what I'd expect given the code I typed, because I don't know how to separate them. Do I need to restructure the whole thing?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartA}{int(random(0,10))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartB}{int(random(0,10))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{int(\PartA+\PartB)}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Structure}{random(1,3)}
}

\newcommand{\onefact}
{
 \InitVariables
 \ifcase\Structure\relax %
  \or
   \newcommand{\Question}{\(\PartA+\PartB=\_\_\_\)}
   \newcommand{\Answer}{\(\PartA+\PartB=\Sum\)}
  \or 
   \newcommand{\Question}{\(\PartA+\_\_\_=\Sum\)}
   \newcommand{\Answer}{\(\PartA+\PartB=\Sum\)}
  \or
   \newcommand{\Question}{\(\_\_\_+\PartB=\Sum\)}
   \newcommand{\Answer}{\(\PartA+\PartB=\Sum\)}
 \fi
}

\newcommand{\thismany}[1] 
{\foreach \x in {1,2,...,#1} { \onefact \par \Question \par \Answer \par}}

\begin{document}

\thismany{10}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but using `\xdef` to create a list is probably the easiest.  Note, `\newcommand` checks to see if the command has been previously defined, so if you don't know or care, use `\def`.

I also made some gratuitous formatting changes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartA}{int(random(0,10))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\PartB}{int(random(0,10))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{int(\PartA+\PartB)}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Structure}{random(1,3)}
}

\newcommand{\Blank}{\,\rule[-3pt]{15pt}{.5pt}\,}

\newcommand{\onefact}
{
 \InitVariables
 \ifcase\Structure\relax %
  \or
   \def\Question{$\PartA+\PartB=\Blank$}
   \def\Answer{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}
  \or 
   \def\Question{$\PartA+\Blank=\Sum$}
   \def\Answer{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}
  \or
   \def\Question{$\Blank+\PartB=\Sum$}
   \def\Answer{$\PartA+\PartB=\Sum$}
 \fi
}

\newcommand{\answerlist}{}% reserve macro name

\newcommand{\thismany}[1] 
{\foreach \x in {1,2,...,#1} { \onefact \Question \par 
   \xdef\answerlist{\answerlist \Answer \par}}}

\begin{document}
\parskip=\baselineskip
\thismany{10}

\newpage
\answerlist

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool. I will take a closer look at this tonight. Thanks!

Comment: I think that I understand the majority of the code. I did not understand this:`\xdef\answerlist{\answerlist \Answer \par}`. I googled `\xdef` but couldn't make sense of the results.

Comment: \xdef is equivalent to \global\edef (expand and define).  We use \edef since \answerlist and \Answer are defined differently each time, so we need to expand them immediately.  We need \global to get the result out of the loop.

Comment: Another question: I am using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` because I was told to but I do not know why. Why not just use `\pgfmathsetmacro`?

Comment: \pgfmathtruncatemacro will convert real to integer without having to use int().