# Solutions Will Not Compile

Tags: pgfmath, exercises

I'm trying to make simple integer exercise pages and solution pages.

Why does this code not compile?

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the `\xdef` line, but I don't know what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\EquationSolution}{}
\newcommand{\EquationExercise}{}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
 \pgfmathrandominteger{\A}{-10}{10} % the first number
 \pgfmathrandominteger{\C}{-10}{10} % the answer
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\A}{\C}}{\InitVariables}{} 
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{int(\C-\A)} % The second number

 \renewcommand{\EquationExercise}
  {%
   \ifthenelse{\B<0}
   {\Large $\A\B=\_\_\_$}
   {\Large $\A+\B=\_\_\_$}
  }

 \renewcommand{\EquationSolution}
  {%
   \ifthenelse{\B<0}
   {\Large $\A\B=\C$}
   {\Large $\A+\B=\C$}
  }
}


\newcommand{\ManySolutions}{}

\newcommand{\ManyExercises}[1]
{%
 \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
  {%
   \InitVariables \EquationExercise
   \xdef\ManySolutions{\ManySolutions \EquationSolution} % Compiles if this line is commented out [along with the other line below]
  }
}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\section*{Exercises}
\ManyExercises{5}
\section*{Solutions}
\ManySolutions % also must be commented out to compile
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\xdef` can never be used on general latex text

Comment: What should I be using instead, then? Or, rather, how else should I compile a list of solutions?

Comment: probably `\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\ManySolutions\expandafter{\EquationSolution}`

Comment: That code is hard for me to make sense of, but I will try anyway. I was able in the past to get `\xdef` working in a very similar situation. For example, see John Kormylo's answer here. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372493/exercise-solution-page

Comment: you should never use `\xdef` except with content that you have constructed directly, It is more or less guaranteed to fail if there is any non ascii letter or almost any command in the content, non expandable commands and very simple macros may be safe but the general rule is that if you use edef or xdef things will break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that breaks within `\xdef` is `\ifthenelse`, then also `\Large` and `\_`.

For `\Large` it's easy: it doesn't belong there, but to an environment around the commands for calling `\ManyExercises` and `\ManySolutions`.

For the other pieces:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\EquationSolution}{}
\newcommand{\EquationExercise}{}
\newcommand{\ManySolutions}{}
\protected\def\dummy{\makebox[2em]{\hrulefill}}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
 \pgfmathrandominteger{\A}{-10}{10} % the first number
 \pgfmathrandominteger{\C}{-10}{10} % the answer
 \ifnum\A=\C\relax\InitVariables\fi
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{int(\C-\A)} % The second number

 \edef\EquationExercise
  {%
   $\A\ifnum\B<0 \else +\fi\B=\dummy$\par
  }

 \edef\EquationSolution
  {%
   $\A\ifnum\B<0 \else +\fi\B=\C$
  }
}



\newcommand{\ManyExercises}[1]
{%
 \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
  {%
   \InitVariables \EquationExercise
   \toks0=\expandafter{\ManySolutions\par}
   \xdef\ManySolutions{\the\toks0 \unexpanded\expandafter{\EquationSolution}} % Compiles if this line is commented out [along with the other line below]
  }
}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\section*{Exercises}
{\Large\ManyExercises{5}\par}
\section*{Solutions}
{\Large\ManySolutions\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know all of those things prevented `\xdef` from working. Now onto the next issue... :)

Comment: Which `\if...` commands work properly in `\xdef` and which ones don't? is there a list for such things?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything That’s not an easy question; but what doesn’t work by pure macro expansion will not survive `\xdef`

Comment: What does "pure macro expansion" mean?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything I have a wonderful explanation for the term, but unfortunately there is a 30K limit on characters in answers. Basically, whatever just need macro expansion and no assignment of values to macros or registers or boxes or…

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66118/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fully-expandable-macros/66168#66168