# Two Font Sizes and \xdef

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, exercises

I need both `\large` and `\huge` fonts inside of `TikZ` diagrams for an exercise for kids to learn that, say, adding a negative is the same as subtracting a positive.

Unfortunately, the font size commands don't seem to survive the `\xdef` command in which they're placed.

I'm trying to create a MWE and having a horrible time doing it... Can anyone answer this question without an MWE? I'll keep working on the MWE until/unless someone can figure this out...

---

EDIT: This isn't really a *minimum* working example, but it has the bug...
I included `\makeatletter` and `\protected@xdef` as recommended in the comments.

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/59f9f7ad53d7fe35b052e16b

---

EDIT 2: I think I may have isolated the problem in [my new thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399536/tikz-solution-set-not-compiling).

---

OR

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{tikz}


%BLANK VARIABLE STUFF
\newcommand{\Operator}{}
\newcommand{\Sign}{}
\newcommand{\Simplified}{}


\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{%
\pgfmathrandominteger{\Type}{1}{4}
\ifcase\Type\relax
 \or    \renewcommand{\Operator}{+}
        \renewcommand{\Sign}{+}
        \renewcommand{\Simplified}{+}
 \or    \renewcommand{\Operator}{+}
        \renewcommand{\Sign}{-}
        \renewcommand{\Simplified}{-}
 \or    \renewcommand{\Operator}{-}
        \renewcommand{\Sign}{+}
        \renewcommand{\Simplified}{-}
 \or    \renewcommand{\Operator}{-}
        \renewcommand{\Sign}{-}
        \renewcommand{\Simplified}{+}
\fi
\pgfmathrandominteger{\Magnitude}{1}{20}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\MagnitudeWithZero}{0}{20}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\NegativeMagnitudeWithZero}{int(-1*\MagnitudeWithZero)}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\VariedSignAndBracketType}{1}{16}
}


\newcommand{\fewer}
 {\draw[blue] (-2.2,-1) rectangle( -1.1,-1.6);}
\newcommand{\more}
 {\draw[blue] (-2.2,-1) rectangle (-1.1,-0.5);}
\newcommand{\gains}
 {\draw[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (0.2,-0.5);}
\newcommand{\losses}
 {\draw[blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (0.2,-1.6);}
\newcommand{\good}
 {\draw[blue] (1.2,-1) rectangle (2.3,-0.5);}
\newcommand{\bad}
 {\draw[blue] (1.2,-1) rectangle (2.3,-1.6);}


%MORE BLANK VARIABLE STUFF
\newcommand{\TwoSignsExercise}{}
\newcommand{\TwoSignsSolution}{}

\newcommand{\TwoSignsGenerator}
{%
\InitVariables
\renewcommand{\TwoSignsExercise}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=center] at (-1.35,0) {\huge $\Operator$};
\node[anchor=center] at (0,0) {\huge $(\Sign)=$};
\draw[dashed, thick] (1.3,-0.4) rectangle (2.3,0.6);
\node[anchor=center] at (-1.6,-0.8) {\large more};
\node[anchor=center] at (-1.6,-1.3) {\large fewer};
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.4,-0.8) {\large gains};
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.4,-1.3) {\large losses};
\node[anchor=center] at (0.6,-1.05) {\large is};
\node[anchor=center] at (1.8,-0.8) {\large good};
\node[anchor=center] at (1.8,-1.3) {\large bad};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%
\renewcommand{\TwoSignsSolution}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ifcase\Type\relax
 \or \more \gains \good
 \or \more \losses \bad
 \or \fewer \gains \bad
 \or \fewer \losses \good
\fi
\node[anchor=center] at (-1.35,0) {\huge $\Operator$};
\node[anchor=center] at (0,0) {\huge $(\Sign)=$};
\draw[dashed, thick] (1.3,-0.4) rectangle (2.3,0.6);
\node[anchor=center, blue] at (1.8,0) {\huge {$\Simplified$}};
\node[anchor=center] at (-1.6,-0.8) {\large more};
\node[anchor=center] at (-1.6,-1.3) {\large fewer};
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.4,-0.8) {\large gains};
\node[anchor=center] at (-0.4,-1.3) {\large losses};
\node[anchor=center] at (0.6,-1.05) {\large is};
\node[anchor=center] at (1.8,-0.8) {\large good};
\node[anchor=center] at (1.8,-1.3) {\large bad};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\ManyTwoSignsSolutions}{}

\newcommand{\ManyTwoSignsExercises}
{%
 \foreach \x in {1,...,10}
  {%
   \TwoSignsGenerator \TwoSignsExercise \vskip 0.25cm
   \protected@xdef\ManyTwoSignsSolutions{\ManyTwoSignsSolutions \TwoSignsSolution}
  }
}


\setlength{\parindent}{0em}




\begin{document}

\section*{Exercises}

\ManyTwoSignsExercises

\section*{Solutions}

\ManyTwoSignsSolutions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\noexpand\large`?

Comment: you should never use `\xdef` on latex input, that's why latex has `\protected@xdef`

Comment: how hard can it be to make a MWE? here is  one: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\edef\zz{\large}\end{document}`

Comment: I think I've already warned you about `\xdef`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397121/solutions-will-not-compile#comment987967_397121

Comment: @egreg It has been quite hard for me to understand some of the warnings because I don't really know what the word "expand" means and haven't found a definitions or explanations that strike me as anything other than incomprehensible jargon. I'm still pretty confused by all the different ways to define and redefine things in LaTeX; I'm baffled as to why more than one way (an equals sign in Python, for example) is necessary.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried `\protected@xdef`, but it doesn't compile. It says I can't use the character `@`. I also have no idea what `protected` actually means.

Comment: you need to use `\makeatletter` to use commands with `@`  in their name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "how hard can it be to make a MWE? here is one:..."   Actually, it can be quite hard for people who haven't mastered LaTeX. I'm trying to create a MWE that isolates the problem of font sizes within `TikZ` within `\xdef` and it seems that there are new problems in my MWE attempts... so I haven't posted it yet.

Comment: it's hardly true that you can define everything in python with just an `=` function definitions, arrays ....  each construct needs a specific definition form, as in most languages

Comment: you should not be using xdef, as stated in comments to your previous question. tikz is not relevant to the error.

Comment: When the definition is question is changed to a simple `\def` it compiles.  What is wrong with that result, for example?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I used `\xdef` because I've used it before. I'm not really sure what it does. In response to your suggestion, I changed `\xdef` to `\def` in the link and it compiles and the exercises appear but the solutions do not.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything There are so many things that break with `\xdef` that's quite hard to suggest a workaround.

Comment: @ egreg , So what should I use instead of `\xdef` to make my solution page? I've tried everything from these comments: `\noexpand\large`, `\make@letter` and `\protected@xdef`, `\def`, etc. and nothing has worked. Am I better off just learn a completely different computer language if I want solutions pages? LaTeX seems to give me problems about 80% of the time and I've found no simple explanation as to why.