# TikZ Solution Set Not Compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, exercises

I've made exercises and solution sheets with TikZ in the past, so I'm not sure why this is failing.

It's just an ultra simple set of 2+2=? exercises and their solutions.

I hope it isolates the problem from [my prior thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/75762/wecanlearnanything).

What did I put in the definition of `\Solution` that is breaking this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\GenerateExerciseAndSolution}
 {\newcommand{\Exercise}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0) {$2+2=?$};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   }
  \newcommand{\Solution}
   {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {$2+2=4$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

   }
  }

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\section*{Exercises}

\newcommand{\SolutionSet}{}

\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
 {\GenerateExerciseAndSolution (\x) \Exercise \par
  \xdef\SolutionSet{\SolutionSet (\x) \Solution \par} % This compiles if I delete "\Solution" from this line.
  }

\section*{Solutions}

\SolutionSet

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you expect if you use `\xdef` ?

Comment: I've tried everything else suggested so far and nothing else has worked. I'm still not clear why `\xdef` fails here but works in so many of my other worksheets with `TikZ`, random numbers, etc. I keep asking for an alternative that actually works, but it seems nobody wants to offer one. I'm thinking of switching programming languages to get around this issue. What do you think of that as an alternative??

Comment: you have asked several questions the answer to each has been essentially don't use xdef on latex constructs, and now you ask another with exactly the same issue.

Comment: "don't use xdef" is not a solution. I've tried literally every other suggestion given in all threads.

Comment: xdef is not a latex command and does not work  if its argument is general latex tokens. So it's pointless to keep asking questions using it. if you started with a previous answer and got stuck applying it then  it 's reasonable to ask a question showing what you did and what error you got. However if you just ignore previous answers and ask the same question again without even highlighting the fact that you are re-using the command that caused the issue last time then there is no point answering as the answers are simply ignored. Someone else may answer but I give up, sorry.

Comment: perhaps you should better use a package like xsim to create your exercises and the solution instead of try to code everything yourself.

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the error is that `\xdef` tries to fully expand what it is given but not everything in LaTeX is expandable. In particular, "complicated" objects like `tikzpicture` environments are not likely to expand. You seem to be assuming that `\xdef` will just plug the "current value" of `\Solution` into `\SolutionSet` but what actually happens is that LaTeX tries to add a huge chunk of code to `\SolutionSet` and this just doesn't work.

As you say in the comments, "'don't use xdef' is not a solution" but I think that there is no easy way to fix what you are doing because the underlying approach is flawed (sorry!). Using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) to typeset a list of questions and their solutions is certainly novel but it is not playing to the strengths of `tikz`, which is primarily for drawing graphics. Something like an `enumerate` environment is likely to be better for displaying exercises.

I suspect that you are using `\tikz` because you want to take advantage of `\foreach` but for what you want to do there are a whole host of expansion hurdles that you will have to solve and I don't think that you want to go there.

Instead, I recommend that you look at the `\docsvlist` command in the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package. This can be used to process a "list" of comma separated variables. The sort of exercise sets that you appear to be dealing with are easy to write as a comma separated list:

```
 1+1 = 2,
 1+2 = 3,
 1+3 = 4,
 2+2 = 4
```

This will also work with more complicated exercises but you should avoid commas and have only one equals sign - or change the syntax!

Given one of these "exercises" we will need to ply apart the exercise and solution. The modern LaTeX way of doing this is to use `\SplitArgument`
from [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package but let's just use a plain TeX hack instead:

```
\def\printExercise#1=#2!!!{\item $#1=\space?$}
```

So, `\printExercise 1+1 = 2!!!` will set `#1` equal to `1+1` and `#2` to `2` with the result that `\item $1+1=\space?$` will be added to the input stream. The `\docsvlist` command applies the command `\do` to each element of the list that it is given, so we just need to make `\do` give the exercise to `\printExercise`. We will also need a corresponding `\printSolution` macro.  Hopefully, this is enough of an explanation for you to work out why the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\printExercise#1=#2!!!{\item $#1=\space?$}
\def\printSolution#1=#2!!!{\item $#1=#2$}

\newcommand\PrintExercises[1]{%
  \section*{Exercises}
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\printExercise##1!!!}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \docsvlist{#1}
  \end{enumerate}

  \section*{Solutions}
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\printSolution##1!!!}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
    \docsvlist{#1}
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\PrintExercises{% comma separated list of exercise: solution pairs
     1+1 = 2,
     1+2 = 3,
     1+3 = 4,
     2+2 = 4
}

\end{document}
```

produces something like the output that (I think), you are looking for:

[image]

In fact, since `\printSolution` is printing the "full exercise-solution equation", and not doing anything with `#1` or `#2`, we can replace `\renewcommand*\do[1]{\printSolution##1!!!}` above with just `\renewcommand*\do[1]{\item $##1$}`. We only need a `\printSolution` macro for "more complicated" processing of the solution -- for example, if we wanted to just print the solution rather than the full equation.

The main trick here is to separate the data -- that is, the exercises and solutions -- from the surrounding LaTeX code that we need to display it. I think that it is always a good idea to keep related parts of the data, in this case the exercises and their solutions, as close together as possible.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything This didn't answer your question?